# Powershell function that adds a element to an existing array element

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I'm trying to create a function that combines a new element with a existing one in an array.
So if I've created an array with 2 indexes and the value in those indexes are "Hello" and I call my function. I need it to take the selected index and combine the two values without overwriting or removing any part of the existing values in the array.

So the array looks like this after the function:

Hello

Hello stackoverflow

instead of:

Hello

Hello

So far this is my code:

```
Function AddToArray ($Index, $Add)
{
#$MainArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;

$MainArray[$Index] = "$MainArray $Add";

$MainArray | % {foreach ($Index in $MainArray[$Index])
{
    $MainArray[$Index] + $Add;
}
}
```

The only thing this accomplishes for me is overwriting the value of the selected index but not combining them.

Any help is appreciated!

Kind regards

Dennis Berntsson

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way too complicated. Just access the element by index and add the new string to it:

```
function AddToArrayElement($MainArray, $Index, $Add) {
  $MainArray[$Index] += $Add
}
```

Example:

```
PS C:\> function AddToArrayElement($MainArray, $Index, $Add) {
>> $MainArray[$Index] += $Add
>> }
>>
PS C:\> $a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS C:\> $a.Add('Hello'); $a.Add('Hello')
0
1
PS C:\> $a
Hello
Hello
PS C:\> AddToArrayElement $a 1 ' StackOverflow'
PS C:\> $a
Hello
Hello StackOverflow
```